# Laravel SQL Problem (I want to specify Last IN and Last OUT time from date)

Tags: sql, laravel

My SQL Table Data Is

```
UserID         Timestamp             EventTrigger
0000003   2019-08-27 08:57:23.000        IN
0000003   2019-08-27 09:07:23.000        OUT
0000003   2019-08-27 09:10:24.000        IN
0000003   2019-08-27 18:05:21.000        OUT
```

I want to make Output like

```
UserID     Date         Last-IN         Last-OUT
 3      2019-08-27      09:10:24        18:05:21
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: hi, welcome to stackoverflow, please do read on our [mcve] guide and revise your question accordingly. we could not help you unless you help us to understand the problem well.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you need to be a bit more specific for people to be able to give good answers, but if you just want a SQL statement which gives the output I think you're asking for, then this should do the trick:

```
select 
    UserId, 
    [IN] as [Last-IN], 
    [OUT] as [Last-OUT]
from
(
    select
        convert(int,UserId) as UserID,
        EventTrigger,
        max([Timestamp]) as LastDate
    from inout
    group by UserId, EventTrigger
) SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    max(LastDate)
    for EventTrigger in ([IN],[OUT])
) as PivotTable
```

This is on the basis of your underlying table definition and data being as follows:

```
create table inout
(
    UserId varchar(10),
    [Timestamp] datetime,
    EventTrigger varchar(3)
)

insert into inout values
('000003','2019-08-27 08:57:23.000','IN'),
('000003','2019-08-27 09:07:23.000','OUT'),
('000003','2019-08-27 09:10:24.000','IN'),
('000003','2019-08-27 18:05:21.000','OUT')
```

You could equally achieve the same result with subqueries:

```
select distinct
    convert(int,UserId) as UserID,
    (select max([Timestamp]) from inout lastin where a.UserId = lastin.UserId and lastin.EventTrigger = 'IN') as [Last-IN],
    (select max([Timestamp]) from inout lastout where a.UserId = lastout.UserId and lastout.EventTrigger = 'OUT') as [Last-OUT]
from inout a
```

Or probably via some other methods like a self-join, or separate queries for each EventTrigger value...

Answer (score 0):

> hope your issue will resolve from this query

```
create table temp(UserID varchar(20),        Timestamp datetime,            
 EventTrigger varchar(10))
 insert into temp values('0000003','2019-08-27 08:57:23.000' ,'IN')
 insert into temp values('0000003'   ,'2019-08-27 09:07:23.000'        ,'OUT') 
 insert into temp values('0000003'   ,'2019-08-27 09:10:24.000'        ,'IN')
 insert into temp values('0000003'   ,'2019-08-27 18:05:21.000'        ,'OUT')


 select I.UserID,cast(I.Timestamp as date) as Date,MAX(cast(case when I.EventTrigger 
 ='IN' then I.Timestamp END as time)) LastTimeIN
 ,MAX(cast(case when I.EventTrigger ='OUT' then I.Timestamp END as time)) LastTimeOut 
 from temp I
 group by I.UserID,cast(I.Timestamp as date)
 drop table temp
```